# How to get timestamp and user ID from a list of string in Python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to extract some parts of text from a list of strings. 
This is how the list looks like:

```
'<rev revid="78273004" parentid="78127030" minor="" user="BF" timestamp="2016-01-19T17:33:57Z" comment="added [[Category:Politics]] usando [[Wikipedia:Monobook.js/Hot Cat|HotCat]]" />', '<rev revid="78127030" parentid="78054777" user="Atar" timestamp="2016-01-15T05:33:33Z" comment="template citazione; rinomina/fix nomi parametri; converto template cite xxx -&gt; cita xxx; elimino parametri vuoti; fix formato data" />', '<rev revid="78054777" parentid="78054533" user="yk" timestamp="2016-01-11T20:50:39Z" comment="/* Voci correlate */  coll. esterni" />', ...
```

I would extract users and timestamps in two different arrays in order to plot them separately.

What I already tried to do is create two different arrays and try to get users and timestamps.

```
url = "https://it.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&format=xml&prop=revisions&rvlimit=500&titles=" + pageTitle
    revisions = []                                        #list of all accumulated revisions
    timestamps = []                                       #list of all accumulated timestamps
    users = []                                            #list of all accumulated users
    next = ''                                             #information for the next request
    while True:
        response = requests.get(url + next).text     #web request
        revisions += re.findall('<rev [^>]*>', response)  #adds all revisions from the current request to the list
        timestamps += re.findall('timestamp="\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}\w\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}\w"', response)
        users += re.findall('user="\w"', response)
        cont = re.search('<continue rvcontinue="([^"]+)"', response)
        if not cont:                                      #break the loop if 'continue' element missing
            break

        next = "&rvcontinue=" + cont.group(1)             #gets the revision Id from which to start the next request

    return timestamps, users;

GetRevisions("Italia")
```

What I would like to get is two arrays, one with timestamps and another one with users.

```
timestamps= [2016-01-19T17:33:57Z, 2016-01-15T05:33:33Z, ...]
users= [BF, Atar, ...]
```

(I would like to make an association between users and timestamps).

However, I am getting only empty lists:

```
[], []
```

I hope you can help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried parsing your text using `BeautifulSoup` ?

You can parse your text as html tags and extract the tags that matter to you, in a simple loop:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

## The text you refer to as list:
yourText = '''<rev revid="78273004" parentid="78127030" minor="" user="BF" timestamp="2016-01-19T17:33:57Z" comment="added [[Category:Politics]] usando [[Wikipedia:Monobook.js/Hot Cat|HotCat]]" />', '<rev revid="78127030" parentid="78054777" user="Atar" timestamp="2016-01-15T05:33:33Z" comment="template citazione; rinomina/fix nomi parametri; converto template cite xxx -&gt; cita xxx; elimino parametri vuoti; fix formato data" />', '<rev revid="78054777" parentid="78054533" user="yk" timestamp="2016-01-11T20:50:39Z" comment="/* Voci correlate */  coll. esterni" />'''

### parse it with BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(yourText, 'html.parser')
users = []
timestamps  = []
for rev in soup.findAll('rev'):
    users.append(rev.get('user'))
    timestamps.append(rev.get('timestamp'))

print (users)
print (timestamps)
```

> > ['BF', 'Atar', 'yk']
> >
> > ['2016-01-19T17:33:57Z', '2016-01-15T05:33:33Z', '2016-01-11T20:50:39Z']

**Using your original code**

Using your original code, we just need to change how your are capturing the texts using regex. The logic I am applying is:

1. Starts with `timestamp=` or `user=`;
2. Followed by `"`
3. Followed by any characters that are not `"`
4. Closed with a `"` character.

```py
timestamps += re.findall('(?:timestamp=)"([^"]*)"', response)
users += re.findall('(?:user=)"([^"]*)"', response)
```

```py
url = "https://it.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&format=xml&prop=revisions&rvlimit=500&titles=Italia"
revisions = []                                        #list of all accumulated revisions
timestamps = []                                       #list of all accumulated timestamps
users = []                                            #list of all accumulated users
next = ''                                             #information for the next request
while True:
    response = requests.get(url + next).text     #web request
    revisions += re.findall('(?=<rev)', response)  #adds all revisions from the current request to the list
    timestamps += re.findall('(?:timestamp=)"([^"]*)"', response)
    users += re.findall('(?:user=)"([^"]*)"', response)
    cont = re.search('<continue rvcontinue="([^"]+)"', response)
    if not cont:                                      #break the loop if 'continue' element missing
        break

    next = "&rvcontinue=" + cont.group(1)             #gets the revision Id from which to start the next request
```

This will yield two lists with 9968 elements:

```py
users[0:3]

Out[1]:
['U9POI57', 'SuperPierlu', 'Superchilum']

timestamps[0:3]

Out[2]:
['2019-07-24T22:15:23Z', '2019-07-24T16:09:59Z', '2019-07-24T12:40:24Z']
```

**EDIT**

Keeping only date, without time. To do so, you just need to replace the end of the matching string from `"` to `T`:

```py
timestamps += re.findall('(?:timestamp=)"([^"]*)T', response)
```

Comment: I have not tried to use BeautifulSoup. Actually, the part of code for collecting the timestamps works, but only when I use the English url. I wanted to understand what  I have been doing wrong in my code, for users, and for timestamps if I use it.wikipedia.org. Many thanks for your help, calestini

Comment: Got it. Would you mind sharing a workable link to try to reproduce your entire code? Thanks!

Comment: Made the changes. The idea is just to correct the regex to capture what is inside the user and timestamp tags (correct me if that's not what you want)

Comment: Thank you so much, calestini. Yes, this is what I wanted. Thanks for your help. Last question: if I want to keep only the date, without time, how can I do?